# Javascript redirect URL

Tags: javascript, java, url, if-statement, redirect

Below is a bit of script I'm using in related to a form for a site. I'm trying to get it to redirect to a specific page if the first two functions aren't valid.

What's happening is that the redirect is happening even if the functions are valid

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple here...

Any help appreciated!

```
(function(){
var f1 = fieldname2,
    valid_pickup_postcode = function (postcode) {
    postcode = postcode.replace(/\s/g, "");
    var regex = /^[O,X]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i;
    return regex.test(postcode);
    };
var f2 = fieldname7,
    valid_dropoff_postcode = function (postcode) {
    postcode = postcode.replace(/\s/g, "");
    var regex = /^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i;
    return regex.test(postcode);
};

if( AND(f1,f2))
{
   if( valid_pickup_postcode(f1) && valid_dropoff_postcode(f2))
   {
      return 'Please select the vehicle you require for your delivery';
   }
   else
   {
      return window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com";
   }
}
else
{
return '';
}
})()
```

Comment: What is the `AND()` function?

Comment: Where do you set `fieldname2` and `fieldname7`?

Comment: Since this is an IIFE, it will be run immediately when the page is loaded, not after the user has filled in any input fields. So how do you expect it to validate user input?

Comment: AND function seems not from javascript, assigning multiple values to f1,f2. Did you check for syntax errors?

Comment: Should the regex variable be a string ?

Comment: Sorry - I'm crappy with JS. This is part of a calculated field form, which the AND function I guess is part of.

Comment: No problem with the regex as a string - those values are being recognised. @Barmar is correct. It's a IIFE. But, is there anyway to make it conditional?

Comment: Conditional on what? Normally code that processes input values is run as part of an event handler, such as the `change` event on the input or the `submit` event on the form.

Comment: There's two fields to be filled in by the user - pickup postcode & drop off postcode. I'm trying to have it so that if the pickup postcode is not an postcode beginning with OX then there will be a redirect to a page which says 'sorry, we don't pickup from that location...etc)

What's confusing me is that other commands instead of 'window.location.href' (such as text) appear fine and work on the above conditions (hence why I'm not worried about the AND thing). Is there a way to redirect without using a IIFE?

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    var f1 = fieldname2,
        valid_pickup_postcode = function(postcode) {
            postcode = postcode.replace(/\s/g, "");
            var regex = /^[O,X]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i;
            return regex.test(postcode);
        };
    var f2 = fieldname7,
        valid_dropoff_postcode = function(postcode) {
            postcode = postcode.replace(/\s/g, "");
            var regex = /^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i;
            return regex.test(postcode);
        };

    if (AND(f1, f2)) {
        if (valid_pickup_postcode(f1) && valid_dropoff_postcode(f2)) {
            return 'Please select the vehicle you require for your delivery';
        } else {
            // return window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com";
            window.location.replace("http://www.bing.com");
        }
    } else {
        return '';
    }
})()
```

`window.location.replace("http://www.bing.com");` should do the trick

**Update**: I have made small changes to make your code work. For something that's as straightforward as validating pickup and dropoff postal codes, the JS isn't (or shouldn't be) very complicated :) Here's a simpler version that will work

```
function myValidator(f1, f2) {
    // Validate pickup postal code
    function pickup_postcode(postcode) {
        if (postcode) {
            if (isNaN(postcode)) {
                postcode = postcode.replace(/\s/g, "");
                var regex = /^[O,X]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i;
                return regex.test(postcode);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Validate dropoff postal code
    function dropoff_postcode(postcode) {
        if (postcode) {
            if (isNaN(postcode)) {
                postcode = postcode.replace(/\s/g, "");
                var regex = /^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i;
                return regex.test(postcode);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (pickup_postcode(f1) === true && dropoff_postcode(f2) === true) { // If both pickup and dropoff postal codes are ok return a message prompting vehicle selection
        return 'Please select the vehicle you require for your delivery';
    } else { // Invalid pickup or dropoff postal code
        // Redirect to website because either pickup or dropoff postal code is invalid
        window.location.replace("https://www.bing.com");
    }
}

myValidator("X909EF", "X909EE"); // Call it this way
```

Comment: Thanks, however I've tried every variation of window.location and it's still automatically redirecting, seemingly because it's an IIFE. I don't understand why the 'else' function doesn't control it!

Comment: Modified the code slightly in my earlier answer. That should work